# How do I configure Postfix to prioritize users over aliases?

Tags: email, postfix

I'm running Postfix on my Ubuntu server, and I'm having a problem with aliases.

As of now, I have a single user account set up (`user@example.com`) on my mail server, a catch-all to `user@example.com`, and a couple aliases redirecting elsewhere.

However, whenever I try to add a new user (`user2@example.com`), my emails still go through my catch-all to my own account. Obviously, this is unacceptable behavior and I need this fixed.

My initial server was set up according to [this Digital Ocean writeup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin).

What can I do to get Postfix's priority to be users, aliases, and then catch-alls?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [I didn't search well enough](https://serverfault.com/questions/675354/postfix-mysql-virtual-users-combined-with-a-catch-all-in-virtual-aliases).

To do this, create a `virtual-cancel.cf` file in `/etc/postfix` with the following information:

```
user = <DATABASE_USER>
password = <DATABASE_PASSWORD>
hosts = <DATABASE_HOST>
dbname = <DATABASE_SCHEMA>
query = SELECT email from <USERS_TABLE> WHERE email='%s'
```

Then, in your `main.cf` file, add your `virtual-cancel.cf` file before your standard alias mapping:

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-cancel.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

Lastly, restart Postfix, and enjoy everything working.